Raid 1 (+0) reports as failed when one drive missing on the underlying raid 1
I have a somehow odd situation, we are trying to solve, but can't figure out.
For one server we have a configuration like this:
md0 : active raid0 md101[1] md100[0]
      642050048 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md100 : active raid1 sda3[1](W) nvme2n1p3[0]
      321157120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/3 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md101 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[0] nvme1n1p3[1]
      321157120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/3 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

This is two raid 1 (md100, md101) combined as a raid 0 in md0 to produce a raid 1+0.
md0 is the assigned as the physical drive of an LVM VG.
We are testing disk failures on boot and mysteriously the partitions on fstab that mount from the logical volumes fail with a fatal error and the system won't boot, even with nofail flags in fstab.
I was blaiming LVM for this but after accessing in maintenance mode I noticed that md100 and md0 report as "inactive" when I remove sda:
md0 : inactive md101[1](S)
      321025024 blocks super 1.2

md101 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[0] nvme1n1p3[1]
      321157120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/3 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md100 : inactive nvme2n1p3[0](S)
      321157120 blocks super 1.2

mdadm reports:
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 1

              Name : a20:0  (local to host a20)
              UUID : 86a127b0:ebb2b28e:b892d07b:98b19065
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       9      101        -        /dev/md/101
/dev/md100:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 1

              Name : a20:100  (local to host a20)
              UUID : 407875f0:a37d4bfc:ac80f39c:b4095741
            Events : 5904

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -     259       15        -        /dev/nvme2n1p3

Which to me is incorrect. Notice that md100 (raid 1) is suddenly reported as "raid0"?
md100 being a raid 1 should boot as raid1 "degraded" and as of my understanding md0 should be either degraded or in normal status.
I am trying to figure out what might be causing this, guessing being related to a superblock being needed to be written at all partitions on the raid or some other boot configuration I am missing.
